# Rails Ziping files - reading binary data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, zip, binaryfiles

I'm using [rubyzip](http://rubyzip.sourceforge.net/) library for zipping files.
But I encounter problems.
I try:

```
    Zip::ZipOutputStream.open('c:/sites/efiling2/test.zip') do |zos|
        zos.put_next_entry("test.rtf")
        zos.write IO.read('c:/sites/efiling2/test.rtf')
        zos.put_next_entry("test.jpg")
        zos.write IO.read('c:/sites/efiling2/test.jpg')
    end
```

But write method restricts a size of original files. For example my source file **test.jpg** has a size of **11913 bytes**, but in archive there is a file **test.jpg** with size **11551 bytes**. With test.rtf there is the same situations.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect your problem may be `IO.read()`. I'm not so sure it does binary data properly.

I would try this instead and see if it fixes the problem:

```
File.open(filename, "rb") { |f| f.read }
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  I spent quite some time on this trying every angle to figure out why my images were missing pieces and your solution solved my problem!